# How to find whether one column is a stricter selection criteria than another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns `col_A` and `col_B`. I want to verify my hypothesis that `col_A` is a stricter selection criteria than `col_A and col_B`. i.e. `select * from table where col_A = something_A` will return the same result as `select * from table where col_A = something_A and col_B = something_B'.

May I know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many times each selection criterion matches:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN col_A = 'something A' THEN 1 END) AS MatchesA,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col_B = 'something B' THEN 1 END) AS MatchesB
FROM table
```

The `CASE` returns `1` if the condition passes or `NULL` if it doesn't. The 1 is summed; the null is ignored.